# How to implement multiple dynamic shortcuts in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-shortcut

I'd like to implement multiple dynamic shortcuts for my application, but the problem is that it allows me to implement only one shortcut.

In my code you'll see two shortcuts, but the application generates only one shortcut.

Can someone take a look on my code and advice me where to make changes?

Here it shows me only one dynamic shortcut
[image: Kotlin]

```
package com.szakes1.makdolannative.activities

import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.ShortcutInfo
import android.content.pm.ShortcutManager
import android.graphics.drawable.Icon
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import com.szakes1.makdolannative.R
import com.szakes1.makdolannative.adapters.ViewPagerAdapter
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager
    private lateinit var pagerAdapter: PagerAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)



        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 25) {
            val shortcutManager = getSystemService<ShortcutManager>(ShortcutManager::class.java)
            val hamburgerShortcut = ShortcutInfo.Builder(applicationContext, "hamburger")
                .setShortLabel("Hamburger")
                .setLongLabel("Wygeneruj kod dla hamburgera")
                .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(applicationContext, R.drawable.ic_hamburger))
                .setIntent(Intent(applicationContext, GeneratedCouponActivity::class.java).setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).putExtra("coupon_image", R.drawable.coupon_hamburger))
                .build()

            val icecreamShortcut = ShortcutInfo.Builder(applicationContext, "hamburger")
                .setShortLabel("Lody")
                .setLongLabel("Wygeneruj kod dla lodów")
                .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(applicationContext, R.drawable.ic_ice_cream))
                .setIntent(Intent(applicationContext, GeneratedCouponActivity::class.java).setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).putExtra("coupon_image", R.drawable.coupon_icecream))
                .build()

            shortcutManager!!.dynamicShortcuts = Arrays.asList(icecreamShortcut, hamburgerShortcut)
        }



        // Sets color for Navigation and Status Bar
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            val color = ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.colorPrimaryDark)

            window.statusBarColor = color
            window.navigationBarColor = color
        }

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout)
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)
        pagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, 5)

        viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both given the same ID "hamburger".

Give the other shortcut a unique ID.

See second parameter at:

```
val icecreamShortcut = ShortcutInfo.Builder(applicationContext, "hamburger")
```